# Hide() function not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, hide

I am creating an app in android/ios(displaying webpages) for which I use a JS menu. The menu `hide()` function works in android browser but not in ios browser(safari). Already tried 
`toggle()`, `blur()`, `hide()`.

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#jsmenu').length) {
        if ($('#jsmenu').is(":visible")) {
            /*  $('#jsmenu').hide();*/
            $("#jsmenu").remove();
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need hide animation then try

```
$('#jsmenu').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: try to use a class name instead of id